# Pi 4 booting but no green LED blinking

Tags: pi-4, board-leds, activity-led

Raspberry pi 4 4GB booting and everything works fine. But no green light blinking. What is the possible reason?

Comment: Do you have an ACTUAL problem?

Comment: both LEDs on the pi4 can be turned off I believe

Comment: Because it is not blinking I don't know if there is problem or not. It was from a fresh boot. I thought I should know if there is something wrong with my hardware although it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

With Raspberry Pi OS I believe by default it only blinks with SD card activity.

Comment: That's the thing. Even if it is working the LED is not blinking. This is a very new sort of problem for me.